# In statistics is there math to fill in empty values.

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I got datasets, width missing numbers.
Those sets are 'mostly' linear.
Though its not strictly linear, there are some slight variations.
So for example:
0, 0, 22 ,23 ,22 ,23 ,20 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 25, 25, 25, 24, 0, 0, 0, 20, 19

I'm curious do there exists methods to fill in the zero's.
I'm a developer and not that deep into statistics.

Currently I'm thinking of taking slope-peaks and fill in the zero's
linear, but I know its not ideal.

However as you  might notice in above data a linear fill is less likely.
As on the right side multiple 25 samples exist (more sure), and on left side it fluctuates more. Is there some math for this to predict the likely  values ?.

Comment: You may want to look up "censored" data on the web. There's lots of literature around this idea.

Comment: Another keyword: interpolation.

Comment: i just read about kriging, another term, not sure if its better i look up your comments as well

Comment: hm kriging wont work because zero data would cause curvatures

Comment: Unclear what you mean by 'linear'. Without some assumptions about the nature of the sequence, I know of no way to fill gaps of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

I said in a comment that some some assumptions would be required.
Here is a possible path. I assume that the non-zero observations
are an actual random sample from a normal population. Also, that
the $0$ observations are errors, such that the actual normal
observation is somehow not recorded.

**Reconstruction using rounded normal values.** Let $Y_1, \dots, Y_{11}$ denote the $n_+ = 11$ non-zero observations.
They have mean $\bar Y = 22.55$ and standard deviation $S_Y = 2.16.$
Then I suppose that the $0$ observations should have been 
a random sample from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 22.55, \sigma = 2.16),$
rounded to integers. Then I replace the $0$'s with such observations.

In R statistical software this procedure can be implemented as
follows:

```
set.seed(1201) # use seed to repeat my restoration exactly, omit for your own
x=c(0,0,22,23,22,23,20,0,0,0,0,0,25,25,25,24,0,0,0,20,19) # damaged seq
y = x[x > 0]             # positive observations 
a = mean(y);  s = sd(y)  # sample mean and SD of positive obs
x.r = x                  # make a copy of x to repair
n.0 = sum(x == 0)        # nr of 0's to repair
x.r[x==0] = round(rnorm(n.0, a, s))  # repaired sequence
x.r
## 19 22 22 23 22 23 20 21 23 24 21 22 25 25 25 24 24 23 27 20 19
plot(x, ylim=c(0,max(x.r))); points(x.r, pch=20, col="green3")
```

In the plot below, the dots without circles are the 'reconstructed' ones.

[image]

**Reconstruction using random choice among values already observed.** Notice that one of the 'reconstructed' values above is (slightly) outside the range of the original
nonzero observations. A more conservative approach would be to use for reconstruction only
randomly chosen values from among non-zero values *already observed.* This limits the choices of reconstructed values, but
does not make any assumption about a normal distribution.

```
set.seed(1202)
x=c(0,0,22,23,22,23,20,0,0,0,0,0,25,25,25,24,0,0,0,20,19)
y = x[x > 0]
x.r = x  # make a copy of x to repair
n.0 = sum(x == 0)
x.r[x==0] = sample(y, n.0, repl=T)  # here is the change
x.r
## 20 20 22 23 22 23 20 19 22 25 24 22 25 25 25 24 25 24 25 20 19
plot(x); points(x.r, pch=20, col="green3")
```

[image]

Both methods rely on some sort of random selection to get reconstructed
values. If you were to run these two programs, omitting the `set.seed`
statement on the first line, you would get somewhat different results.
Here is a second reconstruction using the second approach but with a
seed chosen in an unpredictable manner by the computer.

```
## 20 22 22 23 22 23 20 20 22 19 22 22 25 25 25 24 19 25 25 20 19
```

[image]

*Notes:* (1) I have shown you only two methods out of unimaginably many
possible methods, and without knowing more about your project I can't say I recommend either of them. But maybe these two will give you something to think about. (2) If you think the process is changing over time, you could use
only *recent* non-zero values in the reconstruction algorithm: In the first method, use only recent
values to get the normal mean and SD;  in the second, sample from among only recent non-zero values. (3) Of course, you need to be aware that any
reconstruction method *does not create new information,* but just speculates
as to what missing values might have been.

Comment: Thats interesting, meanwhile i found another method to do it. I'm using a regression neural net. Such networks will try to find the relation in the series. Width one input node and one out put node, and depending on the wanted amount of curvatures twists X hidden nodes. If i have time left i will try to code your solution as well. (but use C#)